# fish shell: how to add a newline before existing prompt?

Tags: shell, fish

I'm happy with the default fish prompt, except I'd like to cause a newline to be printed before it, to give visual separation from the previous command.

Is there some way for me to define a new `fish_prompt` that prints a newline and then somehow defers to the function that was previously known as `fish_prompt`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Copy the prompt to another name, then call it from a new prompt function:

```
functions --copy fish_prompt fish_prompt_original
function fish_prompt; echo; fish_prompt_original; end
funcsave fish_prompt_original
funcsave fish_prompt
```

Answer (score 2):

Since fish does not have name spaces you cannot create two implementations of a function -- one of which calls the other. You will need to run `funced fish_prompt`, insert an `echo` or similar command at the appropriate point, then save it as a private version via `funcsave fish_prompt`.